# RedirectToAction passes to end of current action and goes nowhere

Tags: routes, twilio, castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Here is the controller route that is being hit successfully:

```
[Route("begin")]
    public ActionResult BeginSmsMessaging(SmsRequest message)
    {            
        string from = message.From;

        var phoneNumber = from.Replace("+1", "").FormatPhoneNumber();            

        _commandPipeline.Publish(new LogInboundMessage
        {
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            TimestampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        });

        int code;
        if(int.TryParse(message.Body, out code)) 
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction("DiaryQuestions");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
                return null;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("UnknownCode");
        }
    }
```

Neither the RedirectToAction("DiaryQuestions") nor the RedirectToAction("UnknownCode") are successfully redirecting. Instead, execution moves to the end of the current BeginSmsMessaging action and then slips into IoC code where the controller is released and program execution just stops.

Here is the unreachable DiaryQuestions action:

```
[Route("diaryQuestions")]
    public ActionResult DiaryQuestions(SmsRequest message)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();
        response.SetAttributeValue("PhoneNumber", message.From);
        response.SetAttributeValue("DiaryQuestion", "1");
        response.Message("This is a test message.");
        response.Sms("This is a test SMS");
        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

And the unreachable UnknownCode action:

```
[Route("unknownCode")]
    public ActionResult UnknownCode(SmsRequest message)
    {
        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        response.Sms("What to say...");

        return TwiML(response);
    }
```

No errors are thrown in either the console or Windows Event Viewer. Also, everything looks good up until the RedirectToAction call - input parameters and variables are all populated correctly.

I have no idea at this point what could be happening. :(

Comment: Can you debug step-through the code and see which path it is taking? I'm not sure how it couldn't be returning a value.

Comment: The behavior that I described is exactly what happens when I step through the code. To be more specific, after it hits one of the RedirectToAction lines, it then moves to the ending brace of the current action and then moves directly into Castle Windsor code where the controller is released and execution stops.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it correctly. I very well could be wrong but I don't think this is a Twilio issue but more of a .net mvc issue. I think what is happening when you call RedirectToAction, it causes the browser to do a 301 redirect which would end the current execution path. My .net mvc knowledge is limited though so I could be mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe Andy is probably right in his comments. Because you are returning a redirect, this will send a 301 response to Twilio. I can't easily find documentation on whether Twilio follows those redirects, but I'd assume in this case that it is not.

I'd move the code from your two extra actions, `diaryQuestions` and `unknownCode`, to the original action and return the [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) straight from there.

Something like:

```
[Route("begin")]
    public ActionResult BeginSmsMessaging(SmsRequest message)
    {            
        string from = message.From;

        var phoneNumber = from.Replace("+1", "").FormatPhoneNumber();            

        _commandPipeline.Publish(new LogInboundMessage
        {
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber,
            TimestampUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        });

        var response = new TwilioResponse();

        int code;
        if(int.TryParse(message.Body, out code)) 
        {
            try
            {
                response.SetAttributeValue("PhoneNumber", message.From);
                response.SetAttributeValue("DiaryQuestion", "1");
                response.Message("This is a test message.");
                response.Sms("This is a test SMS");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                string error = e.Message;
                return null;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            response.Sms("What to say...");
        }

        return TwiML(response);
    }
```